# I2C missing last byte during transmission- solution isn't clear

Tags: i2c

I am using a Nodemcu-32S to communicate with an I2C device (touchpads). I noticed while uploading the configuration, the CRC (checksum) always comes back incorrect. After doing a little digging with a logic analyzer, I realized that it never transmits the final byte from my configuration array, which *is* the checksum value. The function I use for writing to the I2C bus is as follows:

```cpp
bool writeI2C(uint16_t address, uint8_t command, uint8_t *data, uint8_t dataLen)
{
    byte err;
    uint8_t dataPos = 0;
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    Wire.write(command);
    for (dataPos; dataPos < dataLen; dataPos++)
    {
        Wire.write(data[dataPos]);
    }
    delay(70);
    err = Wire.endTransmission();
    if (err > 0)
    {
        Serial.printf("writeI2C Error Code: 0x0%d\n", err);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

With the following function call:

```cpp
uint8_t config[128] = {0}; <- (the array is filled with values before the function call)

if (!writeI2C(SLAVE_ADDR, command, config, 128))
        {
            Serial.println("Failed to update config.");
            continue; // try again
        }
```

According to the logic in my function, it should transmit the address, then the register (`command` in this case) followed by 128 bytes of data (130 bytes total). With my logic analyzer, however, I get only 129 'chunks' of data. So I figured I'd add dummy writes if `dataLen` met a condition:

```cpp
bool writeI2C(uint16_t address, uint8_t command, uint8_t *data, uint8_t dataLen)
{
    byte err;
    uint8_t dataPos = 0;
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    Wire.write(command);
    for (dataPos; dataPos < dataLen; dataPos++)
    {
        Wire.write(data[dataPos]);
    }
    if (dataLen > 100)
    {
        Wire.write(0x00);
        Wire.write(0x00);
        Wire.write(0x00);
        Wire.write(0x00);
        Wire.write(0x00);
    }
    err = Wire.endTransmission();
    delay(70);
    if (err > 0)
    {
        Serial.printf("writeI2C Error Code: 0x0%d\n", err);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

None of the dummy writes are outputting and the behavior is the same. The final two bytes should be: `config[126] = 0x45` and `config[127] = 0xC9`, but my logic analyzer is shows that the transmission stops at `0x45 + ACK`.

Answer (score 4):

Within `Wire.h.`:

```
#define I2C_BUFFER_LENGTH 128
```

Changed the buffer length to 140 and it's working just fine.